# Post Multiple Choices in a Poll using C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm having two tables in SQL named 'tblPoll' and 'tblChoices' . I have created an SQL procedure to insert into these two tables. But I want to know how to post multiple choices in the choices model through my post action.

```
Public Actionresult Post(Viewmodels.Poll pModel)
var pollModel = new Models.Poll();
var choicesModel = new Models.Choices();

choicesModel.choice = pModel.choice;
```

I've tried list of string
for the above but it is null. Please guide me what to use to post multiple choices into Choices table.

Comment: Are you want to post multiple selected values from a list which populated in view page using radio buttons (assumed using EF)? There are some missing parts you need to provide by editing.

Comment: Hi I'm using entity framework 6.2.0

Comment: Not by radio buttons but I'm having a textbox for questions and I'm appending multiple textboxes through JavaScript. Now I want to retrieve all the choices values and pass them to choices table

Answer (score 0):

To collect dynamically created form control values use `FormCollection` then loop inside the keys and get the values.

The keys inside `FormCollection` are actually the html control names inside the submitted form.

So, if you have different types of controls (text, radio, checkbox, etc) you can assign a specific prefix for each type of input control e.g.:

```
<input type="text" name="txt_123" value="xxx" />
<input type="radio" name="rdo_123" value="abc" />
```

the value 123 can be the related choice id, so you can collect each type of input controls like below:

```
public ActionResult SubmitPoll(FormCollection model)
{
    foreach(var key in model.AllKeys.where(x => x.StartsWith("txt_")) 
    {
        var value = model[key]
        var choiceId = key.Split('_')[1];
    }
}
```